# The integral of hyperbolic tan

Tags: integration, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

I took two approaches for $\tanh(x) $

1. using $\int tanh (x) dx $ = $\int \frac {sinh x}{cosh x} dx $ , making a u-substitution with $\cosh(x) $ to reach $\ln|cosh(x)| + K$
   which is what I found when I looked it up.
2. using the exponential definition : $\tanh(x) = \frac {e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} $
   I did a u-substitution again with the denomerator and reached : $\ ln |(e^{x}+e^{-x})| $

which is only a factor of $  \frac {1}{2} $ away from the first one. what would be the mistake here ?

Comment: It is a factor $1/2$ away, but at the same time an additive constant $\ln1/2$ away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't made a mistake -the two answers are equivalent as they only differ by the arbritary constant:

$$\ln|e^{x}+e^{-x}|+c= \ln\frac{1}{2}+\ln|e^{x}+e^{-x}| + c - \ln\frac{1}{2}$$

$$= \ln|\frac{1}{2}\cdot(e^{x}+e^{-x})| + c' = \ln|\cosh x| + c'$$

where $c' = c-\ln \frac{1}{2}$